# Assemble a complex object in FormData

Tags: javascript, reactjs, form-data

Please tell me how to assemble such an object in Formdata?

I collected a simple object with text fields through formdata.append (key, value), but with such an object, how to deal with nested objects and an array of files?

Someone cat write an example please?

this is how the server receives data from Postman http://joxi.ru/KAgn9k9iXaae82

```js
let data {
  offer: {
    comment: 'text',
    price: '50'
  },
  files: [File, File]
}
```

Comment: It largely depends on how the server you are posting the data to expects to receive it. The multipart format is a flat list of key=value pairs.

Comment: @Quentin added a link to the screen from Postman

Comment: can you write an example please?

Comment: OK, so with names in square brackets. Loop over the data. Recurse in to objects and arrays. Append other things.